# Removing space between nav border and element inside nav

Tags: html, css, margin, nav

It is not too much of an issue but I wanted to know why there is still a space between the navbar's border and an element that is at the corner. This is my HTML and CSS code along with an image of the problem I am referring to. I have changed the margins but there is still space, I also tried putting the  elements on the same line as the  element but the space still exists.

IMPORTANT: THE MARGIN DISAPPEARS WHEN THE PAGE IS ZOOMED INTO

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 50%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#home" id="ho">Home</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#products">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="signup">Sign Up</a>
</nav>
```

[image: The link when hovered over shows a small space between the border and the hovered element]

Comment: cannot reproduce the issue with the code you have provided. There is nor white-space between the black border and the link element.

Comment: Maybe add a reset for margin and padding to your code?

Comment: So when I zoomed into the page at 100% the margin disappears but as I zoom out the margin appears again, is there a way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen now, I have gave `margin: 8px 0` which was just `margin: 8px`

```css
body {
 margin: 8px 0;
 }

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 50%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#home" id="ho">Home</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#products">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="signup">Sign Up</a>
</nav>
```